# Find whether lat/long coordinate is inside any Leaflet polygon

Tags: coordinates, collision-detection, leaflet, polygon, turfjs

I would like to check which polygon layer (if any) contains a given lat/long (provided by `map.locate())`.

I know you can do this using Turf's [`inside()`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_inside.html) function but is it possible with pure Leaflet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no corresponding Leaflet core method, but you can use https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip plugin.

BTW, the algorithm for checking a point in polygon (ray casting) is just a couple lines of code — you can also easily write it yourself.